# Split link properties

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am stucked, to show the following statement:

Let $L = L_1 \cup L_2$ be a split link. Show that $det(L)=0$ but $\sigma(L)= \sigma(L_1) + \sigma (L_2)$. Where $det$ means the determinant of the link and $\sigma$ his signature.

I know that I should observe the corresponding Seifert matrix of $L$ but I don't know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: by definition, a Seifert surface is a *connected* surface. If the link is split, you can arrange to have tube that connects the seifert surfaces, the "meridian" of this tube is a separating curve that can be one of the generators of $H_1$ of the surface.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but I don't see what important information these give me about the shape of the Seifert matrix, so that I can conclude the given statements...

Comment: That splitting curve has linking number 0 with everything else, so you get a row and column of 0's when you choose it as one of the generators.

Comment: Alright, many thanks! Nevertheless I can't see what the difference is in the seifert surface between the one of a connected sum of knots and the one of a split link... How can I image this connected tube?